# Laravel on Docker: [2002] Connection refused

Tags: laravel, docker

I am trying to put a Laravel app up on Docker, but the database container is giving me trouble.

Specifically, I am getting this error when I try to open the app in the browser:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

But, as far as I can see, all the user credentials are correct. Perhaps I am missing something? Please see below.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: app.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./yoga/:/var/www
    environment:
      - "DB_PORT=33061"
      - "DB_HOST=database"
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: web.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    ports:
      - 8080:80
  database:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: database
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_DATABASE=yogadb"
      - "MYSQL_USER=yogi"
      - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=mypasshere"
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="
    ports:
        - "33061:3306"

volumes:
  dbdata:
```

.env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=database
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=yogadb
DB_USERNAME=yogi
DB_PASSWORD=mypasshere
```

When I run the app outside docker, everything works correctly, I just replace `DB_HOST=database` with `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1`

What can I do to fix this?

docker ps output is:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                NAMES
2da7283f7a65        docker_app          "docker-php-entrypoi…"   19 minutes ago      Up 7 seconds        9000/tcp                             docker_app_1
4801fe3312c1        mysql:5.7           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago         Up 7 seconds        33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:33061->3306/tcp   4801fe3312c1_database
ab370ae1d155        docker_web          "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   25 hours ago        Up 7 seconds        443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp        docker_web_1
```

Comment: change port to  33061 in env file and try

Comment: @GyaneshwarPardhi Same outcome when I change the port to 33061. Weirdly enough, it's also the same outcome when I change the port to something random, like 3365.

Comment: port should be 33061.  check if all the container is running. run  $ docker ps command

Comment: docker ps output added to question above. perhaps the naming of the container isn't correct? I see the container ID is random and not "database".

Comment: yes it should be database then only you will be able to access the db

Comment: But how do I set the container ID then? I thought `container_name: database` in `docker-compose.yml` was supposed to do the trick.

Comment: can you try with version 2

Comment: @jovan You cannot set the container ID. The hostname for MySQL database is the name of service in `docker-compose.yml`, `container_name` is just the name of container.

Comment: @prd Please see my comment on Duy Pahn's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

As @prd mentioned, you need to create bridged network for the containers [1], then add containers to the network [2].

Hostname of container is determined by name of the service in `docker-compose.yml`. In your case, if `app` service will connect to `database` service at hostname `database` & port `3306`.

So `docker-compose.yml` becomes:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: app.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./yoga/:/var/www
    environment:
      - "DB_PORT=3306"                # Port of database container is 3306
      - "DB_HOST=database"
    networks:
      - name_of_network               # [2] add container to network
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: web.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    ports:
      - 8080:80
  database:                           # Name of service, which determines hostname of container
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: database
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_DATABASE=yogadb"
      - "MYSQL_USER=yogi"
      - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=mypasshere"
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="
    ports:
        - "33061:3306"
    networks:
      - name_of_network               # [2] add container to network

volumes:
  dbdata:

networks:
  name_of_network:                    # [1] create bridged network
```

Comment: I tried creating a network as per your instructions, but I got an error from the "web" container, presumably because it wasn't in the network. So I added it to the network, but now we are back to the original issue (connection refused in mysql).

Comment: Did you change the `DB_PORT` on env of `app` to `3306`? And does `app` knows database's username and password?